# Is CouchDb suitable for use on client desktops (Windows 10)?

Tags: sqlite, couchdb

I want to support the users of my Windows 10 desktop application with:

1. Local Data (not having to perform a fetch from the cloud every time they want new data)
2. Offline support
3. Replication with a cloud database

There can potentially be multiple users (in the order of 10-100 but not 1000) simultaneously editing the same database. I would run CouchDb as a service (ie. in a separate process to my app).

To achieve the above I am considering installing CouchDb on each client desktop PC (all replicating to a single main cloud CouchDb instance) together with my application to achieve the above goals.

One of the reasons I am pursuing this line of thinking is that it would allow my application code to mostly just be written in a manner that interacts with local data and the sync/replication (which is probably quite complex) can be taken care of by CouchDb.

I am using CouchDb as a replacement for something that I often see is done by sqlite but I really want the replication ability of CouchDb (which sqlite does not have).

**Is the above a scenario in which I can expect CouchDb to perform well or is there something that I am not considering?**

Comment: Whether CouchDB (or really, anything at all) is suitable for a specific purpose is almost always a matter of opinion. It's more a matter of pros and cons, than "suitability."

Comment: Fair point. I am really just trying to understand if there are any cons that I have not thought of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have multiple clients doing this successfully. This is a recommended use-case for CouchDB. The limiting factor will be the cloud vm configuration, but 100s to 1000s of clients should be no problem on a decent vm setup.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB is sometimes called "A replication protocol with a database attached to it." This sounds appropriate for your use case.  However, installing CouchDB (or any external database/service), particularly as part of a client application, isn't necessarily trivial. That doesn't mean it should be avoided--it's just complexity to consider when making a choice.

You might consider lighter-weight options for your client. PouchDB is the go-to solution for web apps, and often mobile apps, as it syncs with CouchDB, but has much lower resource requirements (at the cost of not being multi-tenant).  For a desktop app, that may be appropriate.

Ultimately, whether CouchDB (or PouchDB, or [PouchDB Server](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server), etc) is appropriate for your use case depends on which trade-offs you're willing to make.

Comment: I'm aware of PouchDb for an in-browser solution but my requirement is for a windows desktop solution. Can you elaborate on the non-trivial items with respect to installing CouchDb on each client?

Comment: I just mean to say that every external dependency adds complexity, and including CouchDB (or any full-blown database) is more complex than including a client library, for example. I don't mean to suggest that it's prohibitively complex. You just need to weigh the pros and cons.

Comment: The CouchDB Windows installer is actually very nice to work with and easy to embed into other Windows installers that you might be using for your own app. By default it installs as a Windows service and you can take it from there. More bespoke configuration, like running as a specific user are possible too, but overall, this should be straightforward.